# Want a counter in aws Dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a table with column "Name" and "Vote", I want to increase the Vote count whenever I do update_item. I tried the below query but no luck.

```
       db.update_item(Key={ "Name":"Dany"}, 
                      UpdateExpression='ADD #oldVote :newVote', 
                      ExpressionAttributeNames={ '#oldVote' :'Vote'}, 
                      ExpressionAttributeValues={':newVote': {"N": "1"}} 
                      )
```

Getting error as:

> "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem
>   operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for
>   operator or function; operator: ADD, operand type: MAP"

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYNkH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below update. It should resolve the problem.

```
db.update_item(Key={ "Name":"Dany"}, 
              UpdateExpression='SET #oldVote = #oldVote + :newVote', 
              ExpressionAttributeNames={ '#oldVote' :'Vote'}, 
              ExpressionAttributeValues={':newVote': 1} 
              )
```

Comment: **Worked! Thanks a ton!**

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
db.update_item(Key={ "Name":"Dany"}, 
                  UpdateExpression='SET Vote = Vote + :incr', 
                  ExpressionAttributeValues={':incr': {"N": "1"}} 
                  )
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters

Comment: **No luck!!**                                                                                             "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: +, operand type: M"

Comment: Are you sure the `Vote` field is currently storing a number? What is "operand type: M" in that error message? Did you include the entire error message in your comment or did you cut off "operand type: MAP"?

Comment: That's the entire error message, I didn't cut short.

Comment: Upvoting for a reference to the documentation.